# ExtJS-Activity-Monitor snippet by arthurakay

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs5

Good day guys can anyone give an example how to use this snippet https://github.com/arthurakay/ExtJS-Activity-Monitor.
I searched this snippet because i want to catch how long the user has  been idle then i saw this     snippet i think it can help me what i want to achieve but i dont know how to use it i just try to insert this  `Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'extjs/examples/ux')` to `my app.js` then i dont know where and how to insert this code :`Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.init({ verbose : true });` Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.start();.

now can anyone help or give me an example like alert message when idle of 1 min so that i can include this to my work Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.init({
    verbose: true
});
Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.start();

Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.isActive = function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Monitor', 'User is active!');
}

Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.isInactive = function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Monitor', 'User is inactive!');
}
```

---

[Something like this. I add more messages for console log, just move mouse in ACTIVITY AREA window, or change chrome tabs for reset invactive counter](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ca3)

Comment: Thanks dude, i saw ur sample its worked but it didnt alert user inactive but in console log it appears inactive user...and im quitely confuse how do i include this to my works ? is this just i include Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.init({
    verbose: true
});
Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.start(); in every js file ? btw thanks again you give me an idea

Comment: u did not get because need to set short maxInactive interval, for example Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.init({ interval: (1000 * 5 * 1), maxInactive: (1000 * 2 * 5) }) // 5 sec interval and 10 sec for max inactive. Yes, monitor is singleton object - just init and use it.